MatterJs don't do animation in nextjs
I'm a newbie in matter.js.I'm using Matter.js in NextJS but it is not working and I don't know why.
This is just a code that I copy and translate to NextJS components.
It displays like this but it doesn't do the animation.
I'm stuck at this problem for one day.
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Matter from 'matter-js';
const Skills = () => {
    const boxRef = useRef(null);
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        let Engine = Matter.Engine;
        let Render = Matter.Render;
        let World = Matter.World;
        let Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
        let engine = Engine.create();
        let render = Render.create({
            element: boxRef.current,
            engine: engine,
            canvas: canvasRef.current,
            options: {
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                background: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                wireframes: false,
            },
        });
        const floor = Bodies.rectangle(150, 300, 300, 20, {
            isStatic: true,
            render: {
                fillStyle: 'blue',
            },
        });
        const ball = Bodies.circle(150, 10, 10, {
            restitution: 0.9,
            render: {
                fillStyle: 'yellow',
            },
        });
        World.add(engine.world, ball);
        Matter.Runner.run(engine);
        Render.run(render);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div ref={boxRef} style={{ width: 300, height: 300,}}>
            <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Skills


World is deprecated. What version of matter.js are you using? Did you see Using Matter.js to render to the DOM or React?

I'm using the version the latest ^0.20.0 - I guess. I have seen the link in your comment and I just copied and pasted it to test but the ball doesn't stop when it touches the ground.

Have a similar issue, in my case the animation doesn't happen on npm run dev but work fine on build and start. Any ideas why this is happenning?

@Abhith Please ask a new question and provide a [mcve].

I had a similar problem, it seems that the latest Matter.js "0.20.0" has issues with Nextjs14, a simple downgrade to "0.19.0" worked for me, in your package.json manually edit:
"matter-js": "^0.19.0"

make sure to run "npm i" then restart your dev server.

Have a similar issue with next,js, in my case the animation doesn't happen on npm run dev but work fine on build and start. Any ideas why this is happenning?
